# DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. in matplotlib program

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

i was learning about matplotlib module in python i have installed the library with using command in command prompt "pip install matplotlib"
and it shows successfully installed  and in python 3.7 IDLE,
when i type import matplotlib  i encounter this error

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 194, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it’s an issue with library versions https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14303

Comment: Yes it worked after installing microsoft visual c++ 2015 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: Has anyone else had this issue? I can't seem to resolve after adding visual C++ and trying the suggestions on the github issues.