# Python import matplotlib fails after successful install using pip on Windows

Tags: python, windows

On Windows 10, I've installed Python 3.7.3. I wanted to add the plot module via `pip install matplotlib` and it seemed to work OK (giving success result), but when trying to import the library with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` it fails saying the specified module could not be found.

I've tried `py -m pip install...` and also `python -m pip install...` none seemed to fix the issue I had.

Here's how I tried to install the module :

```
c:\Users\Michael\Documents>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/e2/f87bf36a2a460857ec9c28535e00102eb6908a727e427adc6427c5dc5453/matplotlib-3.1.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
Collecting pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/d9/3ec19e966301a6e25769976999bd7bbe552016f0d32b577dc9d63d2e0c49/pyparsing-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/6a/e5fff2ed776ab0cd11d7c1d5d3e5e549952464a6f1b9084b7ecbd8341352/kiwisolver-1.1.0-cp37-none-win32.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.16.3)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/d2/e07d3ebb2bd7af696440ce7e754c59dd546ffe1bbe732c8ab68b9c834e61/cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (40.8.0)
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, six, python-dateutil, kiwisolver, cycler, matplotlib
Successfully installed cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.1.0 matplotlib-3.1.0 pyparsing-2.4.0 python-dateutil-2.8.0 six-1.12.0
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Here the path on my computer which includes the python:

```
c:\Users\Michael\Documents>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\;....
```

Here's the error I'm getting (either from idle or from CMD after starting python):

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#61>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 194, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: I recommend you to use anaconda, for python in windows

Comment: Since you get the same error from Command Prompt (which is the right thing to try), this is definitely not an IDLE issue.  You might get better information posting to mail.python.org python-list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this package depends on some C++ libraries which I was missing on my (new) computer, because it worked fine and problem has been resolved after I installed visual C++ 2015 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Thanks to the post on 
[DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. in matplotlib program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285431/dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-in-matplotlib-program)