# dll load failed for matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have installed `matplotlib` in `python`, yet it shows error in import `matplotlib` package.

tried to install manually, uninstalled `matplotlib` package also, and again installed with `pip` command also, but still showing an error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "barcode.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 200, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 194, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: remove the other python version and reinstall python and matplotlib.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. in matplotlib program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285431/dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-in-matplotlib-program)