# I am trying to import matplotlib in python in my system But it is showing me the below error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 159, in _check_versions
    from . import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: This? [DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. in matplotlib program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56285431/3890632)

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and try `pip install matplotlib`

This will download and install the module.

Comment: Try restarting your IDE

Comment: problem also remaining

Comment: try in the console or in jupyter cell 
`!pip install matplotlib`